# Skype for Business - Response group SIP headers

Tags: sip, skype, skype-for-business

We are running Skype For Business 2015 with EnterpriseVoice and want to allow calls coming through response group queues to be forwarded to mobile phones.
We have developed a small app / service to facilitate that through replacement of SIP header names and values according to documentation in

http://blog.greenl.ee/2011/12/30/modifying-sip-headers-managed-sip-application-api/
http://blog.greenl.ee/2013/12/16/response-groups-call-forwarding/.

The replacement seems to work flawlessly, but Skype server still identifies the call as a ‘Team call’ and doesn’t perform simultaneous ring or forward.
Our suspicion is that we replace wrong header details or just one of several needed for S4B to identify the call as a personal call.

Can anyone shed some light on  Skype logic regarding this?
Which headers control the Personal / Team call identification? 
What are correct Name / Value pairs to replace and with what?

There is already a similar post regarding this, but is't about Lync
[Enabling call forwarding for Lync response group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258843/enabling-call-forwarding-for-lync-response-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about 2 different concepts here:

1. Call forwarding control

As said by the linked question, `Ms-Sensitivity` or `Ms-Target-Class` headers are controll if call forwarding is disabled.

So if you want to disable call forwarding to any call, you can add either:

```
request.AllHeaders.Add(new Header(Header.StandardHeaderType.MSTargetClass, "Secondary"));
```

or

```
request.AllHeaders.Add(new Header("ms-sensitivity", "Private-no-diversion"));
```

and you will disable the call forwarding.

If you want to enable call forwarding, remove the headers (as per the Greenlee blog [post](http://blog.greenl.ee/2013/12/16/response-groups-call-forwarding/)).

2. Lync Client Call presentation

This is controlled by the `ms-retarget-reason` parameter in the [History-Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd946646%28v=office.12%29.aspx) header.

For response group calls uses a value of `acd`.

Values that display `Call For` can be:

- `acd` - Displays `Call For` and excepts the call to be transferred after call establised.
- `delegation` - Displays `Call For`.

If you want to remove the `Call For` display you need to remove the `History-Info` headers.

The `Transferred By` display is controlled by the `Referred-By` header.

If you want to control the names display in the `Call For` or `Transferred By` display, you can't from the SIP message.  The lync client looks up and displays the information from a lync contact from the sip address.  If there is no lync contact, it will only display the sip address only.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response. We want to enable call forwarding and proceeded by removing the two headers - but it still will not work. But you gave me some information that I can use, so I will get back to you after some tests

Comment: We still don't get this to work. The call will not get transferred forward to mobile phones through the queues. The headers are removed(only ms-target-class is shown in the sip header), but maybe we are doing it to late?

Comment: I would go through step by step. 1. confirm non queue calls are being forwarded first (to make sure you forwarding setup is correct and working). 2. make sure the headers are removed at least on the primary FE(s) for the users. 3. Confirm the removal of the headers using the Lync Logging tools.  You should be able to see the incoming sip messages with the headers and the out going sip messages without the sip headers.

Comment: Also make sure you proxy is running before "user services" as this is the proxy (I think) that is actioning the forwarding. i.e. the priority is lower than the "user services" priority.  The easiest way is to set it to the same priority as "user services" and you will be inserted just before it.

Comment: Thank you so much! =). It had the wrong prio, changed it via powershell csServerApplication-module. So the solution was: 1. Remove the headers 2. Change the prio 3. Add the <allowRegistrationBeforeUserServices action="true" /> , so you could run the apllication with higher priority. And now it's working. Thanks again and many votes to you